# Android SDK and XQuery?

Tags: java, android, xml, xquery, jtidy

Is there any implementation of XQuery known to work with the Android SDK? I tried mxquery, but had no luck. I did not expect it to work as their site says Andriod support comming soon.

I'm unsing jTidy to parse web pages into XHMTL and am looking for something lite and fast to search, filter and reformat XML files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the javascript port of mxquery: http://www.xqib.org/